# How to control image to be at proper position in 2 column documents?

Tags: positioning, two-column, wide-image

Well, as a beginner, I am having a tough time with images. The dummy code will be a bit long for simulating the situation. I am attaching the two images with exactly the same dimension as the original image. The code content is randomly taken from different published paper, but the location of the items are the same. I can not manage the images to follow their position in the text as per the `main.tex` file.

```
    %\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage[center]{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{./images/}}
    %Table packages
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
    \setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
     \usepackage{makecell}
     \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
    \begin{document}
    \section{Sample Output}
In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.
\subsection{System architecture}\label{System architecture}
In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.% System Components
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Hardware components and specifications}
\label{tab:2}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabularx}
                {\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                             X
                             }
\toprule
\thead{Component} &\thead{ Hardware\\specification} & \thead{Architecture\\application}\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{Android Mobile} & Redmi 4A with Android 8.0, 2GB RAM, 16GB ROM & Client device for data acquisition  \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Processing and monitoring Unit} & Raspberry Pi 4 with 4GB RAM on latest Raspbian OS (December 2020)   &  Main processing unit that runs all the algorithms.\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{WiFi Router(Optional)} & Mi Band-3 high speed router with 70 Mbps Broadband connection & The communication hub for the architecture in indoor monitoring.\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{sample1}
\end{center}
\caption{Basic operational diagram}
 \label{fig:block diagram1}
\end{figure}
In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.
End to end workflow of the proposed fall detection and recovery system with warning message to caregiver and relative is shown in detail in Fig.\ref{fig:architecture}. The primary modules of the proposed system are described below.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item The \emph{Data acquisition module}, residing on the monitoring station, consists of a local storage and is responsible for collection of raw acceleration data from the smartphone sensor. It also stores them locally in addition to forwarding them live, to other modules.
  \item The \emph{Live fall detection module} is responsible for cleaning and analysing the data received from Data acquisition module using Signal Vector Magnitude to detect a possible fall.
  \item The \emph{GPS module} is responsible for mapping the address with the co-ordinates returned by the smartphone GPS. This module is invoked when a fall is detected or there is a fall and break of the device.
  \item The \emph{Integration module} is the coordinating module that is responsible for fetching the location from GPS module (in case the fall response is true from Live fall detection module) and generates the appropriate warning and SMS in addition to record the event locally. It also generates the warning and SMS (single or group) if there is a fall and break of the device.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{sample2}
\end{center}
\caption{Proposed architecture}
 \label{fig:architecture}
\end{figure*}
Fig.\ref{fig:architecture} In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status. The devices and their configuration are listed in Table 2.

\end{document}
```

I am attaching the two pictures for your reference

Sample1[image: Sample1]

Sample2[image: Sample2]

Download the journal template [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OloWtqT5bTmDFnUHOMipG7b9qxxz5Sv-/view?usp=sharing)

Please  help, the document is looking horrible at present.

Comment: I assume you have a problem with Fig. 2? What exactly do you want to achieve? Where should the graph be?

Comment: please use `example-image` as that is a generally available test image, if you use that and adjust any height or width options to check the problem still shows.  Note however that `\begin{figure*}[htb]` spanning figures only support `t` and `p` so that option just prevents `p` being used, `h` and `b` do nothing. `figure*` always appears at the earliest on the following page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid with the `svjour3` class this is the way it behaves, as explained in the `template.tex` they deliver.

Using just one column, you get the result you expected. With two columns, the wide image goes to the top of the next page.

With the standard class `article` you will get a similar result although there are more tools available for more precise control of the floats. See the last figure.

[image: c]

[image: cc]

Done with `article` and `multicol`:

[image: a2c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item The \emph{Data acquisition module}, residing on the monitoring station, consists of a local storage and is responsible for collection of raw acceleration data from the smartphone sensor. It also stores them locally in addition to forwarding them live, to other modules.
            \item The \emph{Live fall detection module} is responsible for cleaning and analysing the data received from Data acquisition module using Signal Vector Magnitude to detect a possible fall.
            \item The \emph{GPS module} is responsible for mapping the address with the co-ordinates returned by the smartphone GPS. This module is invoked when a fall is detected or there is a fall and break of the device.
            \item The \emph{Integration module} is the coordinating module that is responsible for fetching the location from GPS module (in case the fall response is true from Live fall detection module) and generates the appropriate warning and SMS in addition to record the event locally. It also generates the warning and SMS (single or group) if there is a fall and break of the device.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Proposed architecture} \label{fig:architecture}
\end{figure*}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        Fig.\ref{fig:architecture} In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status.In this industrialized world many people live alone and people has to go outside to do their routine job. It is possible that while roaming outside they may face different health hazards. Sometimes they are not in a position to tell someone what they feel about their health or what happened with their health after coming back home. So they may be in critical condition in future for their ignorance regarding their health. HAMR plays an important role in human’s daily activities to indicate the human health status. The devices and their configuration are listed in Table 2.
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use the svjour3 class as it is provided by the journal as template. The main issue is to keep a two column figure that has text above and below the figure. If that is not possible then atleast how to predict after which text the figure will slip to next page ? So that I can adjust the text. Is there anything like the text box of MS word which can accommodate image as well as retain it's position, in LaTeX? Pardon me for nooby question.

Comment: AFIK svjour3 will keep two columns for a whole page. There is no two column -wide figure - two columns on a single page.

 It can be done with `article` as I showed but Springer has it own layout rules, fonts, etc.

The wide figure will go to top of the next page and start two columns.

Common mitigation should be done at the final stage, 
with all the material in place, perhaps changing the text slightly so that the first citation of the figure is on the same page.

Note that in a printed journal it is not a major problem if the figure is on the opposite open page.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose a solution, which you probably will not like. The journal has this class and very likely, this is an intended behavior to arrange different articles in the journal more easily. If you are turning in a paper, you should not expect, that the article will look like your draft in the printed journal or final pdf like it does look on your computer. This might be intended behavior by the publisher, or maybe not. I just want to point out, that there might be a good reason for that. In general, figures are floats and they do float around like the name of the implies. And you should let them do that. If you use parameters like `[ht]` for more than 10% of your floats, you are likely doing something wrong.

What else can you do?

1. From my experience, the best thing is, to refer to the figures from the text in an elaborate way. Write one to three sentences about, what can be seen in the figure. It might be redundant to the caption, but that's not a bad thing. It helps the reader.
2. Use the varioref package. I often used the combination `in figure \vnumref{ABC} \vpageref{ABC} we see ...`.
3. If you need to ensure, that a float doesn't float too far away, use the package placeins with the floatbarrier command. With that, you can define a range, where your float will show up. But don't restrict it to much.